# How to have a filter that depends on a view to a filter foreignkey in django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I defined the **init** method of my form to be able to filter my questions based on the page where I am ...
In my views I already performs this request by this line:

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(page=instance)
```

This retrieves me any question that is on the page or I am ...
I wish I could do the same for display issues on within my form ..

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    page = models.ManyToManyField(Page)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.label

class Reply(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)

def access(request, instance):
    replies = Reply.objects.all()
    pages = Page.objects.all()
    numPages = Page.objects.get(pk=instance)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(page=instance)
    length_questions = len(questions)
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    ReplyFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Reply, form=ReplyForm, extra=length_questions, can_delete=True)
    formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            new_instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for new_instance in new_instances:
                new_instance.user = logged_user
                new_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/baseVisite/')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Le formulaire est incorrecte !')
            return render_to_response('polls/error.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset=Reply.objects.none())
    return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
     'formset': formset,
     'questions':questions,
     'logged_user':logged_user,
     'numPages' : numPages
     })
```

Here is my form and I want to change my filter

```
class ReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reply
        exclude = ('user','creationDate')
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        super (ReplyForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        question = kwargs.get('question')
        self.fields['question'].queryset = Question.objects.filter()
```

**I do not know how to operate the filter but this time in my ModelForm**
Where do I replace `questions = Question.objects.filter(page=instance)`

**How can I pass an instance as a filter in the ModelForm ??**

Comment: think there is a key called `instance` in `kwargs` dict. And also I think you need to override the `get_queryset` method.

Comment: @Avinash Raj How i can do that ?

Comment: Do you have an exemple ?